# defined JSON value always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json

When i try to get a JSON value, also if it is defined it returns undefined. Im trying to do a store system. Here's my code:

```
fetch(link).then(response => response.text()).then(data => {
    try {  
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
    } catch (e) {  
        var json = data;
    }
    console.log(json); //Returns actual json code
    var title = json.title ?? "Store"; //ALWAYS RETURNS "Store"
    var icon = json.icon ?? location.href.replaceAll(location.pathname, '') + "/assets/media/apps/store.png"; //ALWAYS RETURNS "http://127.0.0.1:5500/assets/media/apps/store.png"
    var desc = json.desc ?? title + " is a Reccomended Store."; //ALWAYS RETURNS "Store is a Reccomended Store."
    var type = json.type ?? "2"; //ALWAYS RETUNS "2"
    document.getElementById('store-reccomended-' + i).setAttribute('storetitle', title);
    document.getElementById('store-reccomended-' + i).setAttribute('alt', title);
    document.getElementById('store-reccomended-' + i).setAttribute('storedesc', desc);
    document.getElementById('store-reccomended-' + i).setAttribute('storetype', type);
    document.getElementById('store-reccomended-' + i).setAttribute('src', icon);
});
```

And this is the JSON code:

```
{
    title: "Store Name",
    icon: "/storeicon.png",
    desc: "Eventual Description",
    type: "1"
}
```

Why does this happen and how do I resolve this? I've really searched everywhere but never found anything.

Comment: `then(response => response.text())` will parse the responds and give you a string. Not a JS object. So, yes it is JSON. But you cannot get random properties from a string. Use `then(response => response.json())` instead to parse it into an object.

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/ — your JSON is invalid

Comment: @VLAZ — While `response.json()` is the better approach, they *are* trying to use `JSON.parse()` on the text (and that is failing because the "JSON" isn't valid JSON).

Comment: @Quentin ah, missed that. Well, it's still a string. Don't have invalid JSON, I guess.

Comment: Just in case it isn't clear, I believe the reason the JSON is invalid is due to the keys not being quoted. In a JS object the quotes are not required but in JSON they are.

Comment: `catch(e) { console.log(e);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments already suggest, the JSON is not valid. In a JSON, the object's keys are always in quotes:

```
{
    "title": "Store Name",
    "icon": "/storeicon.png",
    "desc": "Eventual Description",
    "type": "1"
}
```

The second problem here is that you make things a bit complicated. You can just use `response.json()` to parse the JSON data:

```
fetch(link)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => do something with the data)
```

The third problem is that a `fetch()` is asynchronous. So I'd wrap the fetch into an `async` `await`.

```
async function getJson() {
    const response = await fetch(link);
    return await response.json();
}

// store the data in a variable

const data = getJson();

// then use it for whatever
```

For more details about using `fetch()` with `async` `await` read [this](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/) article.